# Replacing byte based on index value in C#

Tags: c#, hex, byte

I am trying to write a console application that will take data as input and split it in to two

example: if i pass a value `0x00000000A0DB383E` as input my output should be look like below:

```
var LowerValue = 0x00000000A0DB0000 (last 2 bytes 383E (index 14-17) replaced with 0000)
var UpperValue = 0x000000000000383E (middle 2 bytes A0DB (index 10-13) replaced with 0000)
```

So far i have tried below but dont know how to proceed further. Any help will be highly appreciated

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace SplitFunction
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        byte[] rawValue = BitConverter.GetBytes(0x00000000A0DB383E);
        SplitData(rawValue);
        Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static byte[] SplitDta(byte[] input)
        {
            byte[] lowerValues =  new byte[8];
            Array.Copy(input, 0, lowerValues, 4, 4);
            foreach(var lowerValue in lowerValues)
                Console.WriteLine(lowerValue);
            return lowerValues;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your input an array of bytes?

Comment: Hi @paulF yes it is

Comment: You do realize that value consists of only 4 total bytes right?  Just inspect the `rawValue` array.

Comment: You code shows you are passing a long value & converting to an array - is that what you want? Or do you want to end up with long values. Note that GetBytes  is likely to get you an array with the low byte first, not last.

Comment: @juharr well, he says it at the top 2 + 2 bytes and  then he uses 8 bytes..

Comment: @sLw: OP needs to make it explicitly long by adding L onto the end of the constant value, otherwise it is truncated to int.

Comment: @sLw The problem is that the `ArrayCopy` is doing 4 bytes, not 2.

Comment: @juharr that's what i meant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than copying & zeroing individual array elements, use masking to create new arrays directly. Something like this :

```
long input = 0x0000000A0DB383EL;

byte[] rawValue = BitConverter.GetBytes(input);
byte[] lowValue = BitConverter.GetBytes(input & 0x000000000000FFFF);
byte[] highValue = BitConverter.GetBytes(input & 0x00000000FFFF0000);
```

if you want the values in order high byte to low byte - then reverse them

```
byte[] rawValue = Array.Reverse(BitConverter.GetBytes(input));
byte[] lowValue = Array.Reverse(BitConverter.GetBytes(input & 0x000000000000FFFF));
byte[] highValue = Array.Reverse(BitConverter.GetBytes(input & 0x00000000FFFF0000));
```

if you simply want the long value rather than an array

```
long lowValue = input & 0x000000000000FFFF;
long highValue = input & 0x00000000FFFF0000;
```

Comment: Hi @PaulF Thank you for your time. First solution was the one i was looking for. I have another question it might be a silly one, how can I convert/represent lowValue and highvalue as 0x0000000A0DB0000 and 0x0000000A0DB000

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by represent lowValue as 0x0000000A0DB0000 (I assume highValue being the same is a typo). If you want the long value - then the last part of the answer is what you need. Or do you mean print that value?

Comment: My bad, and sorry for my poor English, I was asking for how to print. I have figured it. Thank you so much @PaulF